# When i hide bottom navigation or top bar How do I prevent the delayed screen effect?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Let say i have a two screen;

```
@Composable
fun Screen1(
    toScreen2:() -> Unit
) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().border(4.dp, Color.Gray),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        Text(text = "Screen 1")
        Button(onClick = { toScreen2() }) {
            Text(text = "To Screen 2")
        }
    }
}
```

```
@Composable
fun Screen2(
    toScreen1:() -> Unit
) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().border(4.dp, Color.Gray),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        Text(text = "Screen 2")
        Button(onClick = { toScreen1() }) {
            Text(text = "To Screen 1")
        }
    }
}
```

and top bar that I can control the visibility;

```
@Composable
fun MyTopBar(
    currentRoute: String?
) {
    val isVisible = currentRoute == "Screen1"
    AnimatedVisibility(
        visible = isVisible,
        enter = fadeIn(),
        exit = fadeOut()
    ) {
        TopAppBar(backgroundColor = Color.Red){}
    }
}
```

Sccafold

```
val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState()
                val navController = rememberNavController()
                val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
                val currentRoute = navBackStackEntry?.destination?.route
                Scaffold(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize(),
                    scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
                    topBar = { MyTopBar(currentRoute) },
                    backgroundColor = Color.White
                ){
                    NavHost(
                        navController = navController,
                        startDestination = "Screen1"
                    ){
                        composable("Screen1"){
                            Screen1(toScreen2 = { navController.navigate("Screen2") })
                        }
                        composable("Screen2"){
                            Screen2(toScreen1 = { navController.navigate("Screen1") })
                        }
                    }
                }
```

How can i prevent this delayed effect;

i want to instant efect that simultaneously with the disappearance speed of the bottom bar. You can see that the border of the screen lags behind the topbar disappearance speed.

[image]

Comment: I think in this case we should set the topBar in a screen alone and not in the scaffold (unless all the screens in the scaffold need to use the topBar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `AnimatedVisibility` from the `MyTopBar`.

You have animations for the TopBar visibility. So it won't be instantaneous.